# Как правильно отправить через POST запрос текст и получить ответ?

Tags: c#, post

Здравствуйте. Подскажите как правильно отправить через пост запрос какой-то текст и получить ответ. Использую Web service C#. Также как можно получить Ip адрес того, кто отправил пост запрос.

В клиентском приложении
возникает ошибка `The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.`
в строке `WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();`

Код сервиса :

```
using System.Web.Services;

namespace WebService1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Service1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
         public string HelloWorld(string text)
    {

        return "Hello World " + text;
    }
    }
}
```

Код клиента с пост запросом:

```
namespace Examples.System.Net
{
    public class WebRequestPostExample
    {
        public static void Main()
        {

        Console.WriteLine(POST("http://localhost:11364/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld", "lolka"));
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    private static string POST(string Url, string Data)
    {
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(Url);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.Timeout = 100000;
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        byte[] sentData = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(Data);
        req.ContentLength = sentData.Length;
        Stream sendStream = req.GetRequestStream();
        sendStream.Write(sentData, 0, sentData.Length);
        sendStream.Close();
        WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
        Stream ReceiveStream = res.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ReceiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);

        Char[] read = new Char[256];
        int count = sr.Read(read, 0, 256);
        string Out = String.Empty;
        while (count > 0)
        {
            String str = new String(read, 0, count);
            Out += str;
            count = sr.Read(read, 0, 256);
        }
        return Out;
    }
}
```

Вот что требует веб сервис мой на странице тестирования

```
    HTTP POST

The following is a sample HTTP POST request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

POST /Service1.asmx/HelloWorld HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: length

text=string
```

Comment: Вариант с сервисреференсом и прокси классами не подходит по определенным причинам? 

И еще: не пытались фиддлером или еще чем-то отследить\понять причину ошибки? 500 - ето клево, но не понятно..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все оказалось банально, вместо передачи простой строки нужно передавать в таком формате `text=string` , как и просит того сервер  , в итоге строка получилась такой:
`"text= сам текст"`,

Изначально я пытался передать просто `"текст"`.

Answer (score 2):

Откройте http://localhost:11364/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld на сервере, и там посмотрите что надо серверу заслать чтобы соап метод отработал. Там надо именно soap-xml засылать, а не просто адрес дёргать. Если хотите просто адрес, делайте просто сервер.

Comment: Так я и не soap хотел, а http POST, то-есть application/x-www-form-urlencoded засылаю.

Comment: Ну тогда на сервере не web method должен быть

Answer (score 1):

Например так
http://pastebin.com/bJfgNnkf

Comment: Тоже самое. В строке где GetResponse(); вылетает The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. 
Обновил вопрос